# C# Web Service from Microsoft Access Database - Conceptual Issue

Tags: c#, ms-access

So, for reasons uncontrollable by me, myself and a few other developers are required to write a C# Web API to connect to an access database, to allow the data to be returned via JSON for various dashboarding and reporting needs.

Yes, I know this is an odd setup. Basically a client with a legacy Access DB, and they cannot change. Various alternative options have been put forward, but the above is the way it needs to be done unfortunately.

Anyway, my issue is that Access locks the database when opening it.

Scenario:
Client is viewing new dashboard etc. which received it's data from the Web API, which in turn connects to the access database.

All works fine, until the Access DB file is opened with Access to update some values. This kills the connection via the WebAPI with the following error:
[image: Error]

This error only exists whilst the file is open in Access. Once the database is exited, normal service resumes.

Now I've done loads of reading about the interwebs about Access creating locks for users etc, and I know it is probably very bad practice to have multiple users accessing an Access DB at any one time etc.

Am I right in thinking that this is just a limitation of Access, or would there be some way for me to solve web services dying when the Access DB is open within Access? I've looked at the various users and the like, but I cannot seem to find a suitable workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Kindest Regards

Comment: Can you copy the file to another location when the exception occurs and retry then?

Comment: Yeh that does solve the problem, but it doesnt really fit with the user workflow if it were to be rolled out. E.g. user viewing new dashboard, decides to update some values, opens access, dashboard stops working until access closed.

Comment: And when you listen to file change events and copy then? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It sounds like the Access UI users and/or the ASP.NET service account do not have "change" permissions on the *folder* in which the database file resides, so when they open the database in Access they do an implicit "open exclusive".

Comment: Its a right pain, because this is another idea that works on a technical level, but doesnt really fit with the user flow. And has a risk that the DB could be updated in Access, but could then be out of sync with the UI for a period of time. Its frustrating as they basically want a 100% live UI, whilst transationally sound, but without making any changes to existing processes, etc.

Comment: @Gord Thompson - Very interesting. I'll have a research of that right now. :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it is bad practice to have multiple users accessing db at same time, as long as it's done properly. Split the db into backend and frontend and each user runs their own copy of frontend. The backend is linked to and accessed by the frontend. Your frontend is C# web app and Json. Establishing a connection should not lock the backend. So what do you mean by 'opens the db'? The backend is physically opened or is just a connection established?

Comment: @June7 Sorry. To clarify, by opening the db I mean doing what our client does, which is open the DB within access. This also creates the temp lock file which is visible in the filesystem. In a nutshell, the task is to re-create some charts (they currently generate within Access,) in a web interface. But they have the database open in Access a lot, so that cannot take down the web services db connection, which is currently happening probably via the access db file being locked.

Comment: I should have said 'should not lock the backend against other users'. I have managed a multi-user Access db for many years without locking issues. However, my frontend is an Access file. What are the record-locking settings in the backend? Options are: No Locks, All Records, Edited Record.

Comment: As others noted, the opening of the database seems to be "exculsive" and that should not be the case. I would ensure that the web services user has the rights to create files in the same location as the database file. The access data engine "usually" reverts to read only when no locking file can be created but it sounds like the file being opened exclusive and that's not the normal default.

Comment: What actions are the users taking when they open the database in Access?  Are they opening objects in design mode (like tables and forms)?  With Access, opening objects in Design automatically locks the database in Exclusive mode.  Even if not in design mode, clicking the Save (disk) icon can sometimes also revert to Exclusive mode.  What version of Access?  At least in Access 2010 and above, you can set File | Options | Client Settings | Default open mode = Shared (instead of Exclusive).